# I work when I am playing. What am I?

Tags: riddle

Most of you love me

But I got haters too

I play when I am **working**

I am working while I am playing

Sometimes I soothe your mind

What am I?

Comment: None of the answers are always "working while [they are] playing" (practising or even playing for fun / stuck in play mode).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not far from Gareth's answer but I think this could be

> a professional musician

Most of you love me

> fair to say most people like some kind of live music at least?

But I got haters too

> fair to say, most musicians do

I play when I am working

I am working while I am playing

> playing instruments can be work too

Sometimes I soothe your mind

> classical and heavy metal :P

Comment: I was just wondering whether to add an answer saying that when yours appeared :-).

Comment: You got the word "working". Right one

Comment: @BrentHackers your answer is right. I meant profession/job by "working".

Comment: @AJ OK cool.   I think Gareth might be right about the question having a lot of possible good fits though.  Feel's a little like a "Guess what I'm thinking of!" puzzle.

Comment: @BrentHackers perhaps he is, but there are lots of riddles/puzzles of such kind on this site

Answer (score 12):

This feels like there might be multiple equally-good answers, but how about

> a music player (could be CD player, MP3 player, old-fashioned record player, ...)

The clues apply pretty straightforwardly; the weakest link is "But I got haters too" for which the best I can do is

> to observe that e.g. sitting on a bus or train next to someone with loud music playing through their earphones can be *really annoying*.

Comment: Beat me by seconds again +1

Comment: That's a gud answer but not the one I'm looking.

Answer (score 1):

> YouTube

Most of you love me

> Most popular video streaming site

But I got haters too

> Serious issues with Fair Use

And from then on, could apply to

> Any video or music player

Answer (score 1):

Most of you love me

> There are lots of people that love this mind sport

But I got haters too

> Some people thinks it's just gambling

Sometimes I soothe your mind

> Some moves are incredible

I play when I am working

I am working while I am playing

You are

> A professional poker player

Comment: Can you add reasoning to your answer? See other answers for example.

Comment: Gud one, but the reasoning for **I soothe your mind** is not entirely correct because gambling is a game full of tensions as far I know.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a

> portable Bluetooth speaker.

Most of you love me

> Most people love this gadget. Hundreds of thousand of them are sold in a year.

But I got haters too

> But some audiophiles can't stand them because of the sound quality.

I play when I am working

I am working while I am playing

> It's in working order when it can play music. And it's playing while it's working.

Sometimes I soothe your mind

> If you play the right music it might soothe your mind.

Comment: Can you add reasoning to your answer? See other answers for example.

Answer (score 0):

> Music it has haters it is working while it's playing because you can't hear it if it is not playing. it soothes lot of people

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! First of all, please check the existing answers before posting, to make sure your answer hasn't already been posted. Secondly, please hide your answers inside spoiler tags, to avoid potentially spoiling the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves.